# Serial port in windows for Arduino

Tags: python-2.7, windows-7, serial-port, arduino-uno

I'm working on Windows environment and with Arduino.
I have a python script, not written by me, that uses the serial port of linux. 
Since I work on Windows I should convert this code in order to let it work on windows to configure and then use the serial port used by the Arduino attached at the pc. My port is the COM15.i uses windows 7 32 bit. My python distribution is the 2.7.5 and i have installed the pyserial module 32 bit.
The piece of code of interest is the following:

```
def __init__(self,
             port=DEFAULT_DEVICE,
             bps=DEFAULT_DEVICE_SPEED_BPS,
             interval=DEFAULT_INTERVAL):

    self.unpack = None
    self.interval = interval
    self.ser = serial.Serial(baudrate=bps,
                             parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
                             stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                             bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS)

    devs = glob.glob(port + "*")

    for dev in devs:
        logging.debug("scanning %s", dev)
        self.ser.port = dev
        self.ser.open()
        time.sleep(2)
        self.configure()
        self.send_cmds(["#P%u" % self.interval])
        logging.debug("attaching to port %s!", dev)
        return

raise RuntimeError("unable to configure serial port")
```

The "DEFAULT_DEVICE" variable is the one that define the serial port. It is defined as :

```
DEFAULT_DEVICE = '/dev/ttyACM'
```

I think I should simply modify this variable in the format for the serial in windows in order to make the script work  and correctly configure the serial. Searching online I have found that simply putting:

```
DEFAULT_DEVICE = 'COM15'
```

it should work. I have tried in this way but when launching the code I get the raise RuntimeError("unable to configure serial port") defined in the code.
Any idea of the problem? Maybe the format I give to DEFAULT_DEVICE variable is not correct or maybe I should modify something else in the code above. 
Thank you for every help.

Answer (score 0):

if you are only needing COM15, I would simplify it and get the for loop out of there.  Does the code below work?  If not, something on Windows is hung up.

```
port = DEFAULT_DEVICE #'COM15'
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = port
ser.baudrate = DEFAULT_DEVICE_SPEED_BPS
ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS
ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE

ser.open()
ser.write("go\n")
ser.close()
```